# thunderbird inbox conversion

Tags: thunderbird

I have installed the Thunderbird email client and think that the mails are being stored in the files Inbox and Inbox.msf.
Is it possible to convert the Inbox and Inbox.msf files into individual files?

Comment: You can save all emails to `.eml` files via the File dialog.

Comment: I think you have to do that on each email.  I want to operate on the entire Inbox file

Comment: You can select multiple emails and select “Save as”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and use "ImportExportTools" Thunderbird extension (add on). You can mass-export email folders in individual eml files or other. See detailed info in http://www.nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html

If you need to export your folders in other email client, details are in http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail